# HttpException Request timed out on Ajax Calls

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page that has ajax calls on different checkbox selections. At back end web method is called that fills with dataset and returns JSON string response on call. HttpException Request timed out issue is tracked in our error log. This issue is repeating on live server not locally. Almost 100000 users are accessing this page and this is the main page of the site.

I have repeated this issue locally with executionTimeout to set 5 seconds. But on live I can't understand which call is making Httprequest Time Out.

Please suggest if some one has some work around.

Sample code is below:

1. GetASJSON() -- called by jquery
2. LoadData()  -- called in GetASJSON()

/****

Public Shared Function GetAsJSON() As String -- called by Ajax call from jquery

```
    Dim ds As DataSet = LoadData()

    If TotalRecords = 0 Then

        ds = LoadData()
        Message = "NA"
    End If
    Dim _serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()    
    Dim jSonRes As String = String.Empty
    Try
        Dim objects As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            objects.Add(New With {})
        Next                        

        If (objects.Count.Equals(0)) Then
            jSonRes = _serializer.Serialize(New With {._Status = "Error", ._Message = "No Arrangement Found"})
        Else
            jSonRes = _serializer.Serialize(New With {._Status = "OK", ._Data = objects, ._Message = Message})
        End If
    Return jSonRes
End Function
```

******/

Private Shared Function LoadData() As DataSet

```
Dim ds As DataSet
ds = ds = ManagerClass.GetByFilter(param1, param2, param3)

 Return ds

End Function
```

Comment: you need to enabling logging at critical points in the application and determine what is slowing down the system...

Comment: can you please write down code where its generating exception. So we can understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Without having much details about the request timeout value in the live server or knowing what the underlying issue is, you could try to add this to the web.config in your live application which will set the request time out in seconds:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also, if you are running IIS you can use the **Failed Request Tracing**. You can set it up to dump traces of any request taking more than X amount of time.

Comment: in Config executionTimeout is default on server.

Comment: @SajidNadeem I updated my answer with some ideas on how to troubleshoot and find the underlying issue.